# Prepostion query

Tags: prepositions

Delhi
This is a list of judges of the Supreme Court of India, the highest court in the Republic of India. The list is ordered according to seniority. There are currently 22 judges (including Chief Justice of India) AGAINST a  maximum possible strength of 31. As per the Constitution of India, judges of the Supreme Court retire at age 65.

Could anyone tell me what does AGAINST mean over here .I have tried to find the meaning of AGAINST  but none of the meaning fits over here . So please explain me properly the meaninf of AGAINST and what the sentence is trying to convey THANK YOU SO MUCH .

Comment: [Entry number 8](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/against)

Answer (score 0):

It means "in comparison to."  In this case, the writer is pointing out that there could be up to 31 judges, but currently there are only 22.  It's a somewhat slang usage of the term, from "to compare against" which refers to a simple comparison technique of holding one thing literally against another thing to accentuate the differences.